# How can I change/monkeypatch model.auth Group __str__ method?

Tags: python, django, django-models, monkeypatching

I want to monkey patch Django Group model with new `__str__` method.
I know how to monkeypatch Group's manager but it doesn't work with `__str__` method.

That's new method that I want to put in Group model:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name if 'test' not in self.name else self.virtual_group.title
```

virtual_group is related name to another model and I want to take it's title and replace.

What I want to achieve?
I have in my database groups like this:

```
Super Group 
Extra Group 
New Group 
test_1 
test_2 
test_3 
Great Group
test_4 
(...)
```

test_X groups are one to one field with related name `virtual_group`. I had to to this that way, because I need unique name in groups, but visible names can be the same.

I just wanted to change `__str__` method to automatically change groups name 'test_x' to normal string from related model's title.

I've tried something like this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name if 'tour' not in self.name else self.virtual_group.title

Group.__str__ = __str__
```

or this:

```
class Group(Group):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name if 'tour' not in self.name else self.virtual_group.title
```

Then with manager:

```
class DefaultGroupManager(models.Manager):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name if 'tour' not in self.name else self.virtual_group.title

    def get_queryset(self):
         (...)

dgm = DefaultGroupManager()
dgm.contribute_to_class(Group, 'objects')
Group.objects = dgm
```

But none of these worked, I have no errors, but nothing happens

I can't create new extended model because that requires changing milions lines of code. Like Group to ExtendedGroup(Group).

I will appreciate any help!

Comment: So what happens instead? Do you get an error? Can you show us the output you expect, and what you see happen in its place? Please include a full traceback if there is one.

Comment: `Group` is just a regular Django model, just like `GroupManager`, monkeypatching doesn't work any different. But why not just [extend the model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) instead of monkeypatching the core classes?